# Measuring latency over network

Tags: c++, performance, latency, measure

I have a program that will run in two different computers like: Server and Client. I want to measure the latency over the network in my program in C++ and Java. The normal commands to measure the runtime (such as `gettimeofday` in C) I think are not very accurate for run latency over the network. Some advice?

Comment: `normal commands to measure the runtime` - what are you referring to? What's wrong with regular ping?

Comment: @Pavel is edit my question. I'm referring to commands such as gettimeofday

Comment: Do you want to know the end-to-end latency (i.e., one-way) or the round-trip latency (e.g., ping)?

Comment: @Jonas I'm interesting in end-to-end latency

Comment: @PRVS I was afraid you might say that :)  The problem is that for some resolution tolerance the clock synchronization should be around an order of magnitude better. This synchronization has been a problem for a long time, there are nice approximations like using PTP or others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can measure accurate time with [std::chrono](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono)

```
#include <chrono>

auto timeStart = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
// do something... wait for result...
auto timeEnd = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

long long duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(timeEnd - timeStart).count();
```

Replace `microseconds` with `nanoseconds`, `milliseconds`, `seconds` to get duration in different units.

You may as well use [std::clock](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/clock) though it might provide less accurate measurements:

```
#include <ctime>

std::clock_t timeStart = std::clock();
// do something... wait for result...
std::clock_t timeEnd = std::clock();

double durationMs = 1000.0 * (timeEnd-timeStart) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!!

Comment: this applies to end to end latency ?

Comment: @PRVS by using clock or chrono timers you can measure duration of time that it takes to do some action. So, if you send something to the server and wait for reply, then you can measure overall duration which should roughly estimate round trip time between you and your server.

Comment: Ok that's work for what I want. Thanks for the explanation.